# Error de The underlying provider failed on Open. en EntrityFramework en MVC asp.net (time out)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
  public ActionResult partialListadoFichas(string departamento, string centro)
    {
            using (personal_Entities bd = new personal_Entities())
            {

                string sql = "select";
                sql += " CAST(CONCAT(fichas.rut, '-', fichas.dv) AS CHAR(11)) AS rutcompleto";
                sql += ",fichas.appat";
                sql += ",fichas.apmat";
                sql += ",fichas.nombres";
                sql += ",DATE_FORMAT(fichas.fechacontrato,'%d/%m/%Y') AS fechacontrato";
                sql += ",fichas.duracioncontrato";
                sql += ",DATE_FORMAT(fichas.fechatermino,'%d/%m/%Y') AS fechatermino";
                sql += ",DATE_FORMAT(fichas.fechaprorroga,'%d/%m/%Y') AS fechaprorroga";
                sql += ",DATE_FORMAT(fichas.fechafiniquito,'%d/%m/%Y') AS fechafiniquito";
                sql += ",DATE_FORMAT(fichas.phheefechat,'%d/%m/%Y') AS phheefechat";
                sql += ",fichas.centrocosto";
                sql += ",fichas.cargo";
                sql += ",fichas.referencia";
                sql += ",DATE_FORMAT(fichas.fechanac,'%d/%m/%Y') AS fechanac";
                sql += ",fichas.nacionalidad";
                sql += ",fichas.sexo";
                sql += ",fichas.procedencia";
                sql += ",fichas.profesion";
                sql += ",fichas.talla";
                sql += ",fichas.calzado";
                sql += ",fichas.domicilio";
                sql += " from fichas where fichas.periodo=@periodo and fichas.mes=@mes and fichas.obra=@obra and fichas.empresa=@empresa";
                if (centro != "")
                {
                    sql += " and centrocosto=" + centro;
                }
                if (departamento != "")
                {
                    sql += " and cajapago=" + departamento;
                }

                string periodo = Session["ss_periodo"].ToString();
                string mes = Session["ss_mes"].ToString();
                string empresa = Session["ss_codigoempresa"].ToString();
                string obra = Session["ss_obraEstablecida"].ToString();


                var parametros_sql = new object[]
                {
                    new MySqlParameter("@periodo", MySqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = periodo },
                    new MySqlParameter("@mes", MySqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = mes },
                    new MySqlParameter("@obra", MySqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = obra },
                    new MySqlParameter("@empresa", MySqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = empresa },
                };

                List<FichasModel> query = bd.Database.SqlQuery<FichasModel>(sql, parametros_sql).ToList();

                var lista = query.ToList();
                return View(lista);

            
        }
    }
```

Pero a veces, me sale el siguiente error:

**'The underlying provider failed on Open.'
SocketException: Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder**

**System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException
HResult=0x80131501
Mensaje = The underlying provider failed on Open.
Origen = <No se puede evaluar el origen de la excepción>
Seguimiento de la pila:**

**Excepción interna 1:
MySqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.**

**Excepción interna 2:
TimeoutException: No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder.**

**Excepción interna 3:
IOException: No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder.**

**Excepción interna 4:
SocketException: Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder**

Me gustaría saber como evitar este tipo de error, ¿será que en la web.config habrá que agregar algún parametro para regular time out?¿A caso no es tan eficiente trabajar con EntityFramework?, ¿Será mas conveniente trabajar con datareader?

Observación, así tengo la cadena de conexión en la web.config:

```
<add name="personal_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BD_EntityFramework.csdl|res://*/BD_EntityFramework.ssdl|res://*/BD_EntityFramework.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;allowzerodatetime=True;convertzerodatetime=True;server=123.123.123;user id=xxx;password=xxx;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=personal_demo;port=xxx&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: 1. Verifica si tienes el motor de base de datos activo y si puedes conectarte desde otro lado. 2.Revisa si tienes correctamente ese cadena SQL, de preferencia utiliza un string Builder en lugar de concatenar el mismo texto una y otra vez. 3. Revisa bien la documentación del conector del mysql, hasta donde tengo entendido se paga si se realiza aplicaciones comerciales. 4. Esa consulta, ¿las has probado y te trae los datos que buscas? Considera que el ORM conecta los resultados con clases (mapping) y si son diferentes, te lanza error.

Comment: 5. Si hay una enorme cantidad de datos para traer, considera utilizar un paginador donde traes solo una parte de esa masa de información.

Comment: @fredyfx, muchas gracias por la respuesta. En respuesta a tu pregunta, si me trae los datos, lo extraño que a veces ocurre el error. La base de datos es de un servidor.
He pensado que puede ser el rendimiento del PC que a veces se puede saturar en memoria. Me llama bastante la atención del String Builder, tienes algun ejemplo?, como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Sí, mira: https://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder

Comment: @fredyfx, podrá ser algo así:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8